# Unhide, unprotect and run macro from another spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently teaching myself VBA. I work with Excel 2010 a lot but only know the basics of VBA.

To help teach myself, I have set a project for myself which is to create a dashboard in Excel where I can click a button and it opens three reports I run each morning at work and runs a macro on each. The process of each report is to
1 - open report 
2 - unhide worksheet (worksheet = "Control Sheet")
4 - run macro on the unhidden sheet (macro = "ButtonClick")
5 - hide worksheet
5 - Save and close report

I have managed to get 1 report to open using:

```
Sub EasierRun()

Dim Location As String

Location = "location/filename.xlsm"

Workbooks.Open(Location).RunAutoMacros (xlAutoOpen)

End Sub
```

I copied the 2nd to last line from the internet but it doesn't run any macro, it just opens the file. No error messages display. I understand that I need to be specific about the worksheet and macro I want to work with but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Also, I'm not sure if I need to tell it to unhide the worksheet in the VBA? Finally, would I need to write individual code for each report to open or do I declare the files all at once and then the remainder of the code works universally?

I've googled and read a lot but I can't manage to adapt what I am finding to fit what I need.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, for security purposes, you can't force a workbook to enable macros without explicit input from the user.